# Combine drop down with textbox using html/css

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a requirement where I need to show some data by combining textbox and dropdown.
It actually looks like a textbox with left side section is a textbox, and right side is a dropdown. On clicking the drop down, options are shown with size equal to textbox and the drop down.

```
<span class="class1" style="display: inline-table;"> 
            <span class="class2"> 
                <input class="class3" type="text" style="margin-left: 0; box-shadow: 0 0 0 0; border-right: 0" name="topFrameSearchValue" id="topFrameSearchValue"/>
            </span> 
            <span class="class4">
            <ul id="menu">
                <li class="class5"><a href="#">Recent</a>                   
                        <ul class="sub-menu">
                            <li>
                                <a href="#">Sub Menu 1</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#">Sub Menu 2</a>
                            </li>
                         </ul>

                </li>
            </ul>
            </span>
        </span>
```

I succeeded in joining the textbox and the drop down, but not able to extend its size till text box.

Link to the image which shows the design: 
i57.tinypic.com/do464n.png

Created a jsfiddle, :[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dmajumdar/r92vE)

Comment: can you please share jsfiddle?

Comment: do you have any additional CSS and jquery code too?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/dmajumdar/r92vE/

The Submenu items shold cover the drop down and text box.

Comment: not getting what exactly you want to do, can you please elaborate more? you can add images to explain better.

Comment: @BhushanKawadkar : http://i57.tinypic.com/do464n.png

Answer (score 0):

Use a datalist tag. It is new element in HTML5. Here is the code -

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<form action="demo_form.asp" method="get">
<input list="browsers" name="browser">
<datalist id="browsers">
    <option value="Internet Explorer">
    <option value="Firefox">
    <option value="Chrome">
    <option value="Opera">
    <option value="Safari">
</datalist>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But cant use html 5.. :(

Answer (score 0):

Managed to form this Ui with following code:

HTML:

```
 <div id="container" style="display:inline;">
        <input id="topFrameSearchValue" name="" type="" style="width: 95px;border:0px solid #000000;">

        <select id="searchHistory" name="" style="width: 180px;" onChange="updateTopFrame()">
        </select>
        </div>
```

CSS:

```
   #container
  {
position: relative;
margin-top: -5px;
padding-bottom: 3px;
```

}

```
#topFrameSearchValue
{
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
z-index: 999;
padding: 0;
 margin-left: 2px;
margin-top: 1px;
font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size: 9pt;
outline: none;

}

 #searchHistory
 {
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 margin: 0;
 text-align:right;
 color: #999999;

-webkit-appearance:none;
-moz-appearance:none;
  display: inline-block;
 border-color: #cccccc;
 font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
 font-size: 7pt;
 outline: none;
 }
```